# How to remove foreign value in JSONB array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to remove foreign key in my jsonb array

This is my array `v_msgar`

```
OBX|||0^RBC||5.58|^10â¶/Î¼L|3.85-5.78||||F
OBX|||1^HGB||15.6|^g/dL|12.0-17.2||||F
OBX|||2^MCV||84.3|^fL|78.0-96.0||||F
OBX|||3^HCT||47.0|^%|34.8-50.9||||F
OBX|||4^MCH||28.00|^pg|26.40-33.20||||F
OBX|||5^MCHC||33.2|^g/dL|31.8-36.7||<EOT>||F
OBX|||6^RDWsd||*39.9|^fL|0.0-0.0||||F
OBX|||7^RDWcv||15.1|^%|13.1-24.6||||F
OBX|||8^PLT||214|^10Â³/Î¼L|172-440||||F
OBX|||9^MPV||8.9|^fL|6.1-9.1||||F
OBX|||10^PCT||0.19|^%|0.07-0.49||||F
OBX|||11^PDWsd||11.0|^fL|0.0-0.0||||F
OBX|||12^PDWcv||*49.6|^%|0.0-0.0||||F
OBX|||13^WBC||7.7|^10Â³/Î¼L|3.7-11.7||||F
OBX|||14^LYM||2.8|^10Â³/Î¼L|1.1-3.6||||F
OBX|||15^LYMP||36.5|^%|14.1-52.8||||F
OBX|||16^MID||*0.5|^10Â³/Î¼L|0.2-1.2||||F
OBX|||17^MIDP||6.6|^%|3.2-17.7||||F
OBX|||18^GRA||4.4|^10Â³/Î¼L|1.9-7.9||||F
```

My code goes

```
SELECT json_agg(jsonb_build_object('resultValue',substring(split_part(parts[6],'^',1),1,5)))
               INTO v_reading
               FROM unnest(v_msgar) as elem,
                     regexp_split_to_array(elem, '\|') as parts
               WHERE parts[1] = 'OBX';
```

How to remove `*` sign if there is `*` sign in resultValue reading

Comment: Your example data is not an array, just the text. There is no `*` sign in your example data. And your example data is redundant, I think two lines should be anough.

Comment: `select translate('*39.9', '*', '');`?